# GraphQL: field.resolve() result is undefined inside directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I've been following all the results I found on Google on how to make an AuthDirective but I can't make it work.

I'll leave all the files to see if I'm making an error on the implementation but I guess not because I tested even without having any conditions inside the field.resolve.

One particular thing I found is that field.resolve, comes with 4 args, the first of them is always undefined, not sure if that could be it but just as an additional tip.

So here's the code:

This is a part of my typedefs

```
directive @isAuthenticated on FIELD_DEFINITION

scalar Date

type User {
    id: ID,
    name: String
    email: String
    password: String
    createdAt: Date
}

type Token {
    token: String
}

# IF I REMOVE @isAuthenticated this works!
type Query {
    user(name: String): User! @isAuthenticated 
    users: [User!]! @isAuthenticated
}

type Mutation {
    createUser(name: String, email: String, password: String): Boolean!
    login(email: String!, password: String!): Token!
}
```

Here is my schema:

```
import path from 'path';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { fileLoader, mergeResolvers, mergeTypes } from 'merge-graphql-schemas';
import schemaDirectives from './Directives';

const typedefsArray = fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './**/*.graphql'));
const resolversArray = fileLoader(path.join(__dirname, './**/*.resolvers.ts'));

const typeDefs = mergeTypes(typedefsArray);
const resolvers = mergeResolvers(resolversArray);
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers, schemaDirectives });

export default schema;
```

Here is my AuthDirective

```
import { defaultFieldResolver } from 'graphql';
import { AuthenticationError, SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from 'apollo-server-express';

class AuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field: any) {
    const { resolver = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

    field.resolve = async function (...args: any) {
      const [_, __, context] = args;
      const { req } = context;
      const accessToken = req.headers.authorization
        ? req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
        : null;

      if (accessToken) {
        // here I was doing jwt.verify(accessToken) but I removed it for now to simplify
        const result = await resolver.apply(this, args);
        return result; // <--- THIS IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED
      } else {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Unauthorized field');
      }
    };
  }
}

export default AuthDirective;
```

which lives under ./Directives and is being exported from an index as:

```
import AuthDirective from './auth';

export default {
  isAuthenticated: AuthDirective
}
```

Finally my user resolver. Like I said before, if I remove the directive from the user graphql query its working as it should:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { AuthenticationError, UserInputError } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { IUser } from './IUser';
import UserModel from './user.schema';
import { Config } from '../../config';

const { APP_SECRET } = Config;

const createToken = async (user: IUser, secret: string, expiresIn: string) => {
  const { id, email, name } = user;
  return jwt.sign({ id, email, name }, secret, { expiresIn });
};

const userResolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (_: any, { name }: { name: string }) => UserModel.findOne({ name }).exec(),
    users: () => UserModel.find({}).exec()
  },
  Mutation: {
    createUser: async (_: any, args: IUser) => {
      await new UserModel(args).save();
      return true;
    },
    login: async (_: any, { email, password }: IUser) => {
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email }).exec();

      if (!user) {
        throw new UserInputError('No user found with this login credentials.');
      }

      const isValid = await user.validatePassword(password);

      if (!isValid) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Invalid password.');
      }

      return { token: createToken(user, APP_SECRET, '30m') };
    }
  }
};

export default userResolvers;
```

and my server:

```
import morgan from 'morgan';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import depthLimit from 'graphql-depth-limit';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';

import { Config, DBConfig } from './config';
import schema from './domain';
const { PORT } = Config;

const app = express();

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  validationRules: [depthLimit(7)],
  context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({ req, res })
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

DBConfig.init();

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `resolver` property on `field`, so this

```
const { resolver = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
```

will always result in `resolver` having the value of `defaultFieldResolver`. If you're using the directive on some field that had a custom resolver, that custom resolver is never being called -- only the default behavior is used, which could indeed return `undefined`.

You need to make sure you're using the correct property:

```
const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
```

or you can rename the resulting variable when you destructure `field`:

```
const { resolve: resolver = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
```

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid, tested everything except that! Thanks for your quick response